# Reliable Background Geolocation Service on Android in JavaScript

Tags: android, cordova, react-native, titanium, nativescript

The app should track the user in the background, do some calculations on locations received and notify the user of some events of interest.

The logic has already been written in JavaScript (for post-mortem analysis). So, to not re-implement the same in Java/Swift, I'm aiming to **Cordova/ReactNative/NativeScript/Titanium**.

Android could kill a backgrounded app in tight memory conditions. To make background operation more reliable, Android Service could be used. One could make the service "foreground" to tell the OS that the user is aware of the service and the service is of importance to the user. The OS will rarely kill such app/service process. Even when it does we could ask it to re-start the service ASAP.

The problem is that it looks like JavaScript VM is not started with the service and there is no way to run JavaScript logic. The same problem for all frameworks mentioned.

Thus, the service must be all-native and we are back to the re-implementation of the logic.

Questions:

1. Are my findings correct? I.e. in either mentioned framework there is no easy way to re-start JavaScript VM from the service?
2. Somewhere on SO I saw a trick where the service ran an (invisible) Activity which instantiated the VM again. Is it possible? Can you give a link/explanation?
3. How often will Android kill a process hosting "foreground" service? Maybe I could just ignore this case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app which is completely reliant on reliable background geolocation on Android (and iOS).

After trying many approaches (including my own native solutions) I have settled on [cordova-background-geolocation-lt](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt) (also available for [React Native](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation) and [NativeScript](https://github.com/transistorsoft/nativescript-background-geolocation-lt)).

It's a paid-for solution (not free), but there's a reason for that: in my extensive real-world field testing, it was the only solution to work reliably on all OS versions (including Android 8 and iOS 11) - Android 8 in particular is a challenge due to new [background geolocation limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits.html).

In answer to your questions, in practice I have found this solution very reliable on Android when using the [foregroundService](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/blob/master/docs/README.md#config-boolean-foregroundservice-false) option, with my app able to run continuously for several hours with no interruption.